# Splitting a row of multiple words into seperate rows each containing one word

Tags: sql, database

I have a Database that contains two columns, a date and then a column that is a sentence. Example: "2016-12-5" "I went out to the mall today". How can I split these columns of sentences into a single word per row while still keeping them connected to the correct date?

Comment: We always ask the same question: SQL Server or MySQL? at least do not use tags which you don't know what it is

Comment: I remove both of tags, please edit your question and add only the DBMS you are really use.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `split` function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(@String VARCHAR (max), @Delimiter CHAR (1))
RETURNS 
    @temptable TABLE (
        [items] VARCHAR (max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL)
AS
begin        
    declare @idx int        
    declare @slice varchar(max)        

    select @idx = 1        
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return        

    while @idx!= 0        
    begin        
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)        
        if @idx!=0        
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)        
        else        
            set @slice = @String        

        if(len(@slice)>0)   
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)        

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)        
        if len(@String) = 0 break        
    end    
return        
end
```

After creating the function, try this:

```
SELECT '2016-12-5' AS [Date],items Value FROM dbo.Split('I went out to the mall today',' ')
```